# Notice: Undefined index: id

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Tengo un formulario con `php` y `html`, en el cual, quiero modificar mi Base de Datos. Solo que estoy en confuso con este mensaje de error.

*Formulario*

```js
<?php
 
    require('../admin/conexion.php');

  $id=$_GET['id'];
  $query="SELECT empresa, marca, modelo, n_serie, tipo, procesador, vel_procesador, memoria_ram, disco_duro1, disco_duro2, sistema_operativo, g_inicio, g_final FROM computadora WHERE id='$id'";
  $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
  $row=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
 
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Modificar - Computadora</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
 background-image: url(../imagenes/imagen_student.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    </head>
    <center>


    <table>
    <form method="POST" action="modificar_computadora.php"> <!-- Archivo PHP de llamada -->
 
 
    <div class="container">
    <p><br/></p>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">


    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="page-header">


    <h3>Modificar Computadora</h3>





            

    <!-- Formulario de llamada -->

            <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Empresa</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "empresa"  value="<?php echo $row['empresa'];?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail-->"
            </div>



            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Marca</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "marca" value="<?php echo $row['marca']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Modelo</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "modelo" value="<?php echo $row['modelo']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">N° Serie</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "n_serie" value="<?php echo $row['n_serie']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tipo</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "tipo" value="<?php echo $row['tipo']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Procesador</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "procesador" value="<?php echo $row['procesador']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Velocidad del Procesador</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "vel_procesador" value="<?php echo $row['vel_procesador']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Memoria RAM</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "memoria_ram" value="<?php echo $row['memoria_ram']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>



            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Disco Duro 1</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "disco_duro1" value="<?php echo $row['disco_duro1']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Disco Duro 2</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "disco_duro2" value="<?php echo $row['disco_duro2']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Sistema Operativo</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "sistema_operativo" value="<?php echo $row['sistema_operativo']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Garantia Inicio</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name = "g_inicio" value="<?php echo $row['g_inicio']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>


            <form role="form">
            <div class="form group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Garantia Final</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></span>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name = "g_final" value="<?php echo $row['g_final']; ?>" <!--id="exampleInputEmail2-->"
            </div>



            <hr/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span>Atras</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Modificar</button>


            <p><br/></p>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            

  <span class="form-group"></span>

  </div>
  </div>
  <form>
    
    

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    

  </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php 
 
 require('../admin/conexion.php');
 
 $id=$_POST['id'];
 $empresa=$_POST['empresa'];
 $marca=$_POST['marca'];
 $modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
 $n_serie=$_POST['n_serie'];
 $tipo=$_POST['tipo'];

 $procesador=$_POST['procesador'];
 $vel_procesador=$_POST['$vel_procesador'];
 $memoria_ram=$_POST['$memoria_ram'];
 $disco_duro1=$_POST['$disco_duro1'];
 $disco_duro2=$_POST['disco_duro2'];
 $sistema_operativo=$_POST['sistema_operativo'];

 $g_inicio=$_POST['$g_inicio'];
 $g_final=$_POST['$g_final'];
 
 $query="UPDATE computadora SET empresa='$empresa', marca='$marca', modelo='$modelo', n_serie='$n_serie', tipo='$tipo', procesador='$procesador', vel_procesador='$vel_procesador', memoria_ram='$memoria_ram', disco_duro1='$disco_duro1', disco_duro2='$disco_duro2', sistema_operativo='$sistema_operativo', g_inicio='$g_inicio', g_final='$g_final' WHERE id='$id'";
 
 $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
 
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Modificar Computadora</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <center>
   
   <?php 
    if($resultado>0){
    ?>
    
    <h1>Computadora Modificada</h1>
    
     <?php  }else{ ?>
    
    <h1>Error, Computadora NO Modificada</h1>
    
   <?php } ?>
   
   <p></p> 
   
   <a href="../menu_principal.php">Menu Principal</a>
   
  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: y en qué linea se supone que te marca el **Notice**?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\Inventario\computadora\modificar_computadora.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: $vel_procesador in C:\wamp64\www\Inventario\computadora\modificar_computadora.php on line 13

El modificar computadora.php es el UPDATE.

Comment: Tu formulario no manda ningún dato `'id'` a través de `POST`  a tu archivo PHP, es decir ningun input tiene el atributo `name='id'`, por no hablar porque tantos tags de `form` ya que es algo que no está permitido hacer.

Comment: Ya le he agregado el `id` @Lixus  y luego se salta a Notice: Undefined index: $vel_procesador in C:\wamp64\www\Inventario\computadora\modificar_computadora.php on line 13

Comment: `vel_procesador !== $vel_procesador`, debes quitar el `$`

Comment: SOLUCIONADO! 
Era el `$`. Gracias por contestar @Linus

Comment: Ahora tienes otro error, no es Linus, es @Lixus. :) Resuelto este problema, considera el uso de consultas preparadas en tus consultas que incluyan criterios WHERE tomados de fuentes externas, de ese modo previenes contra la Inyección SQL.

Comment: Me equivoque :(
(Gracias por el tip @A.Cedano)
:)

Comment: ¿Se cierra por no relacionado (error ortográfico) o te animas a una respuesta @Lixus?

Comment: Estoy esperando que @Lixus responda la pregunta para cerrar el tema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema aquí es que en tu formulario no existe un input cuyo nombre sea id:

```
<input type='text' name='id'/>
```

Debido a esto no se envía a la variable POST y al llegar al archivo php, este no reconoce el índice `id` del arreglo `$_POST`

Debes de incluír dicho input dentro de tu formulario para que pueda reconocer la variable. Y otro error más es en el índice `$_POST['$vel_procesador']` está mal escrito, debe de ser `$_POST['vel_procesador']` de lo contrario te ocurrirá el mismo error que con `id` y no te reconoceá el índice.

Answer (score 1):

En tu PHP al iniciar a correr el código estás recibiendo por método `GET` la variable `$id`, cuando la variable no ha sido enviada a la página actual bien sea desde un `form` en la misma página o en una página externa, la variable está vacía y el aviso que te aparece te está indicando eso.

Ahora, para ocultar estas notificaciones mientras la variable está vacía puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);
```

En tu código quedaría así :

```
    require('../admin/conexion.php');
  error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  $query="SELECT empresa, marca, modelo, n_serie, tipo, procesador, vel_procesador, memoria_ram, disco_duro1, disco_duro2, sistema_operativo, g_inicio, g_final FROM computadora WHERE id='$id'";
  $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
  $row=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
```

Con eso te debería dejar de aparecer el Notice.

Revisa que estés enviando al archivo la variable `$id`, si no, no podrás realizar la consulta SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yo he revisado mi codigo y tengo declarada la Variable 'id' en un campo option dentro del formulario y me seguía apareciendo el mismo error. Pero agregue ese código y me funciona bien

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Y que hace ese código ? Por favor lee [answer]